# Displaying user input html with newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have comments section in my application where users enter input in a text area. I want to prevent the line breaks they enter but also display html as a string. For example, if `comment.body` is

```
Hello, this is the code: <a href='foo'>foo</a>

Bye
```

I want it to be displayed just as above. The same with anything else, including `iframe` tags.

The closest I got is:

```
= simple_format(comment.body)
```

but it sanitizes html code and it's not displayed. Example: `foo <iframe>biz</iframe> bar` is displayed as:

```
foo biz bar
```

What should I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Question, do you want the tags to render as HTML, or do you want the tags to render as text?

Comment: As text - like I pointed in my question.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to print the comment.body as html escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it without any method, it will be rendered as plain text:

```
= comment.body
```

Using your second example, the output will be:

```
foo <iframe>biz</iframe> bar
```

To make `\n` behave as `<br>`, you can use CSS:

```
.add-line {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

And use it in your view:

```
.add-line = comment.body
```

Using your first example:

```
comment.body = "Hello, this is the code: <a href='foo'>foo</a>\n\nBye"
```

The output will be:

```
Hello, this is the code: <a href='foo'>foo</a>

Bye
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML safe allows the html in the comment to be used as html, but would skip the newlines, so doing a quick replace of `\n` with `<br />` would cover the new lines

```
comment.body.gsub("\n", "<br />").html_safe
```

If you want the html to be displayed instead of rendered then checkout `CGI::escapeHTML()`, then do the gsub so that the `<br />` does not get escaped.

```
CGI::escapeHTML(comment.body).gsub("\n", "<br />")
```

Comment: Double check yout output, `CGI::escapeHTML` will not render `<`/ `>` as it will escape them and show `&lt;`/`&gt` instead, so you will get something like: `foo &lt;iframe&gt;biz&lt;/iframe&gt; bar`.

Comment: @Gerry yes, when printed to screen in a console. because that is the html escaped content, so when rendered in a view it will display as `<iframe>biz</iframe>` instead of actually creating the `<iframe>` tag with the word biz inside it

Comment: Have you tested it? You will need to add `raw()` (i.e. `raw(CGI::escapeHTML(comment.body).gsub("\n", "<br />"))` to get the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Having done something similar in the past, I think you must first understand why HTML is sanitized from user input.

Imagine I wrote the following into a field that accepted HTML and displays this to the front page.

```
<script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

The code would execute for anyone visiting the front-page and annoyingly trigger a JS alert for every visitor.

Maybe not much of an issue yet, but imagine I wrote some AJAX request that sent user session IDs to my own server. Now this is an issue... because people's sessions are being hijacked.

Furthermore, there is a full JavaScript based exploitation framework called BeEF that relies on this type of website exploit called Cross-site Scripting (XSS).

BeEF does extremely scary stuff and is worth taking a look at when considering user generated HTML.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

So what to do? Well if you checked in your DB you'd see that the tags are actually being stored, but like you pointed out aren't displayed.

You could `.html_safe` the content, but again I strongly advise against this.

Maybe instead you should write an alternative `.html_safe` method yourself, something like `html_safe_whitelisted_tags`.

As for removing newlines, you say you want to display as is. So replacing `/n` with `<br>`, as pointed out by Michael, would be the solution for you.

```
comment.body.gsub('\n', '<br />').html_safe_whitelisted_tags
```